# Modelling horizontally scaled applications in ArchiMate using Sparx enterprise architect

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architect, enterprise-architecture, archimate

I'd like to model a horizontally scaled application in ArchiMate using the Sparx Enterprise Architect. As I can not include the same element twice in a diagram: How can I show, that an application will run in multiple instances?

Comment: Knowing little about the Archimate (MDG) but probably you have to create instances by just doing so: ctrl-drag to diagram and choose instance. There are more Archimate gurus on Sparx' forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of two options for issue:

1. Use the multiplicity/cardinality on the connector end of your "horizontally scaled application" to indicate the number of instances running
2. Use *artifact instances* of your application and drop them multiple times on the diagram

   When running EA Validation the following at least the connectors do not raise a warning or an error (as seen in the 3rd figure): `Assignement`/`Association`, `Access`/`Dependency` and `Flow`/`ControlFlow`

[image: Application with Multiplicity]
[image: Application Component as Artifact Instances]
[image: Model Validation Results for Artifact Instances]

Comment: I'm afraid the second approach wouldn't be valid in an ArchiMate model.

Comment: Thanks @GeertBellekens for the hint. I replaced the elements with ArchiMate3 elements and replaced the component instances to Artifact instances.